# adding a number to each id and anchor tag with php

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to add a number to each div and anchor tag dynamically. I cant wrap my head around this. I have several accordions with dynamic data and i need to add a id with a number so i can be able to toggle open and close the accordion. So i need to add a number to each id. The issue is when i just add this variable it keeps adding the numbers up and doesnt match up to its parent.

In order for my accordion to work the anchor tag and the div tag need to have the same id.

```
    <?php $i = 0; ?>

    <div id="accordion-<?php echo ++$i;?>" >
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo ++$i;?>" href="#details-0-<?php echo ++$i;?>" data-toggle="collapse" >
        Click me to toggle
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="details-0-<?php echo ++$i;?>">
      <div class="panel-body">

Data goes here
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this code between a loop?

Comment: No. Its in a IF statement @Daan

Comment: I don't know how you're toggling these -- if it's with JavaScript you probably don't need to use ID's at all.

Answer (score 2):

Basically : remove every `++` except for one. For simplier code, add it in a separate instruction.

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>

<?php $i++; ?>
<div id="accordion-<?php echo $i;?>" >
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $i;?>" href="#details-0-<?php echo $i;?>" data-toggle="collapse" >
    Click me to toggle
  </a>
</div>

<div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="details-0-<?php echo $i;?>">
  <div class="panel-body">
     Data goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does the same thing. It adds the numbers up so it closes the one above. @blue112 Thanks for the help though

Comment: @BeEasy did you re-try it after the edit? This should't close the one above, because all `$i` are the same value with this approuch.

Comment: yes all my Id's are the same number value. I need them to be separate for example accordion-1, accordion-2, etc. they all have accordion-1

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your code in a loop and remove all ++ like this

```
<?php $accordionQuantity = 5; ?>

<?for($i=0;$i<$accordionQuantity;$i++):?>
<div id="accordion-<?php echo $i;?>" >
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $i;?>" href="#details-0-<?php echo $i;?>" data-toggle="collapse" >
    Click me to toggle
  </a>
</div>

<div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="details-<?php echo $i;?>">
  <div class="panel-body">
     Data goes here
  </div>
</div>
<?endfor;?>
```

Comment: this sort of works but it duplicates my data. not sure why @ragnar

Comment: You have to store your data in an array $array = ['data1','data2'...]  and <?echo $array[$i]?>